# eeepc 701SD 4G Power Up Fails - Will not power up / boot

Tags: power-supply, eee-pc, crunchbang

**I have a critical failure with my eeepc 701SD 4G:**

**Will not power on at all.**
 - Power button pressed = nothing happens at all. absolutely nothing.
 - Battery light shows orange and doesn't charge
 - AC Power Adapter plugged in shows battery light orange and doesn't charge.

**Tested AC Power Adapter:**
I have tested the power adapter on an external HDD of mine and it powered up fine.
 - = NO SUCCESS

**Tested Battery:**
Purchased a new extended life / 10400mah battery. 
 - = NO SUCCESS

**Tested RESET BUTTON PROCESS:**
http://goo.gl/zKtjqe

- When returning battery and AC Power - first green LED lit up for about 30 seconds then the battery lit up orange
- = NO SUCCESS

**The last time it was working was 6 months ago.**

System Info:
Model: eeepc 701SD 4G 
OS:    Linux (Crunchbang)
           - Recovery partition retained.

Anyone else having or have solved this issue?

Comment: Sounds like it needs a new motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

It's relatively uncommon on an eee, but the symptoms sound like a broken solder joint on the power connector.  Happens all the time on certain popular laptops; I've just never heard of it on an eee.  What happens is that there is enough connection for the laptop to know that the adapter is plugged in, but not enough to actually charge the battery.  The symptoms you describe match what is often seen if the power connector isn't totally broken off.

But since you did get one flash of green, you might try keeping it plugged in for 8 hrs & then try again;  it could just be taking a very long time to charge up.

FWIW, make sure you have no external USB devices plugged in.  An eee that I owned a while back would essentially short out if anything was plugged into the left-side USB connectors ... a known issue, annoying as all get-out.  I'd forget, be going along & plug in a stick, and that annoying whooshy-whee sound would accompany it going abruptly dead.